# How to format a text like bold/italic in UITextField in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Here consider this image. I have taken a toolbar with icons for text formatting. After selecting that sentence if I hit B (*bold*) it should be bold. Even I need that too if I select bold then further text to be show as bold. Consider this textbox UITextField. Incase you have some good reference like github you are welcome. I have already spend two days in a row in SO but not get any proper solution. One bold function is enough for me.

[image]

Comment: `NSAttributedString`, that's the right class to look for for addition "effects" to a text. For the rest, you are asking for is a small "WYSIWYG", maybe "WYSIWYG + Swift" might give you pointers...

Comment: I think you need a UITextView not a UITextField.

Comment: @Leo Yes, by default it supports. Bold, Italics, Underline. Even I need a bulletpoints text for UITextView. So I have to do more customization like MS Word. Incase you got solution let me know.